# Istio in AKS with DNS

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I deployed the book  application from Istio in a AKS cluster that has a Loadbalancer and a custom domain. Here is the `gateway.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "x.myaks.domain"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "x.myaks.domain"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080
```

The problem is, when I navigate in my browser to `x.myaks.domain/productpage`, I get an DNS unresolved error. Does anyone know how to expose services with Istio in AKS clusters under a domain?

Doing `curl -H "Host: x.myaks.domain" loadbalancerip/productpage` works perfectly

**Update**

I just have the info that an automatic DNS entry in Azure is created when the Ingress ressource is defined.

1. Is it possible to use istio with an Ingress ressource?
2. If not, how to secure the data between an istio envoy proxy and the nginx ingress controller?

Comment: can you also share your `productpage` service yaml in order to have a complete picture of your setup.

Comment: sure, but that is just the bookinfo example of istio

Comment: ok, no worries, I'll take it from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.2/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml

Comment: Thanks. I will concretise my question since I have a new info

Comment: Yes, you can use istio together with ingress. Here is a relevant discussion - https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-without-gateway-with-nginx-ingress/593

Comment: thanks I will take a looka t

Comment: do you still need help with this case?

Comment: I just tried that out and I did not get it to work. It seems like the "connection" between Ingress of nginx and the virtualservice of Istio is not working? Have you made it work to have an nginx Ingress with an Istio virtualservice?

Comment: Your cluster setup looks good, so let's start from the very beginning: Do you own the domain, which you are trying to use `x.myaks.domain` ?  Have you configured Azure NS records in the registrar for your domain?

Comment: Hi, yea I own he domain and when creating an A-record manually it works, but it should work automatically like using Ingress ressources. With ingress ressources, DNS is configured automatically

Comment: automatically created DNS records based on host names specified in ingress objects is valid only when ExternalDNS addon is enabled and configured. https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/azure.md

Comment: yea I think the coreDNS is delivered by AKS right?

Comment: yes, right. Also you have to set `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname` annotation on the service to let ExternalDNS pick up a dns name

Comment: that solved it :o thanks so much!!

Comment: great, I'll put it as an answer for the future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ingress objects **ExternalDNS** will create a DNS record based on the host specified for the ingress object.

For services **ExternalDNS** will look for the annotation `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname` on the service and use the corresponding value.